# Reading & character that is being passed through GET

Tags: php, get, query-string, html-encode

I am reading content of `GET` query string, and every time I encounter `&` for ecample `Blackstone Woodfire & Grill`, `GET` is reading `Blackstone Woodfire`.

How can I avoid this, if possible?

I know I could encode the special characters from the reference page, then decode them when are directed to this page.

I'm just curious.

Comment: You shouldnt need to decode it, that should be done automatically.  Can you do a `var_dump` of `$_GET`?

Comment: *How* are you reading the querystrig? What is the exact input and exact code that you're using? Seeing that `&` is delimiter character and is omitted because it serves as the delimiter, if you want to "read" the `&` sign, it should be encoded as `&amp;` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Flosculus, I understand that PHP will read this as separate GET variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the parameters you send using get, are separated using a &.
So if you have an url like

```
 http:/example.com?param_1=value_1&param_2=value_2
```

You will have an $_GET array like

```
array(
    param_1 => 'value_1',
    param_2 => 'value_2'
);
```

Now if you send and url like:

```
 http://example.com?param_1=value_1 & value_2
```

You will have an $_GET array like

```
array(
    param_1 => 'value_1 ',
    ' value_2' => ''
);
```

Simply becuase that is the way sending GET params works.
On the recieving side, there is not much you can do, the problem lies at the other end.
The GET parameters that are beeing send must indeed be encoded, within PHP that is done using

```
 echo 'http://example.com?param_1=' . urlencode('value_1 & value_2');
```

Javascript uses encodeURIComponent() to solve this issue.
PHP calles urldecode() automaticly on every get parameter when it is creating your $_GET global.

Answer (score 0):

You could use urlencode to encode the get string. And later if u want to fetch it from $_GET u urldecode.

You could replace all ampersands to %26